# Why signature of the form "save()" method should match base Form class in django?

Tags: python, django, pylint

For instance, I have following code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import FormView


class MyModel(models.Model)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()


class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def save(self, owner, commit=True):
        self.instance.owner = owner
        return super().save(commit)


class MyView(FormView):
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name = 'my_template.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

If I run pylint on that code, it gives following error:

```
[W0221(arguments-differ), MyForm.save] Arguments number differs from overridden 'save' method
```

Is it a bad practice to do that? Should I set `owner` in the view `form_valid` method?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Instead of using a different signature, why don't you call save with commit=False; this will return the model instance. You can then add the appropriate attributes, in this case owner, and save the model directly.

Comment: The main question is about design. I mean, it can be done in the view, but if there is not one field from request(like owner in this case), but 10 or 50. This leads to the code duplication and tighter coupling.